# I can't seem to figure out a way to compute a gradient without reference coordinates

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, dipole, dipole-moment, multipole-expansion

I'm not sure if this question is better asked here or in *Mathematics* but here it goes:

I'm studying electric dipoles, and this exercise I'm working on asks for the energy between 2 dipoles, given by $$U_{DD}=-\vec{p}_1\cdot\vec{E}_2\,\,.$$
The thing is that I can't advance from here since I don't really know how to calculate the gardient of the potential without using a coordinate system for reference, something the solutions simply say not to do, but don't explain how.

What I've got so far is as follows:

$$V_2=K_e\frac{\vec{p}_2\cdot\hat{R}_2}{R_2^2}=K_e\frac{p_2\cos(\theta)}{R_2^2}$$
$$\vec{E}_2=-\vec{\nabla}V_2=\frac{K_e\cdot\vec{p}_2}{R_2^3}(2\cos(\theta)\hat{i}+\sin(\theta)\hat{j})$$

When the electric field shown in the previously referenced solutions is $$\vec{E}=K_e\frac{3(\vec{p}\cdot\hat{r})\hat{r}-\vec{p}}{r^3}\,\,.$$

My question essentially boils down to: how do I go from the first expression for $\vec{E}$ to the second one, or in an even shorter form, how do I prove the following equality $$p(2\cos(\theta)\hat{i}+\sin(\theta)\hat{j})=3(\vec{p}\cdot\hat{r})\hat{r}-\vec{p}$$

Comment: Have you drawn a diagram representing all your vectors? It might help you rewrite the trig functions in terms of r.

Comment: @Triatticus, 

I have, but discarted that approach right away, to be honest. 

I was also thinking that I could just also define $\vec{p}$ using $\theta$ for that same coordinate system. 

What's really bugging me is how I can't seem to be able to get the no reference coordinate system of $\vec{E}$.

Comment: Well you might want to include your work for the trig functions, ultimately the more you provide in work you've tried the more helpful we can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the identity
$$\nabla(A\cdot B) = A \times (\nabla \times B) + B \times (\nabla \times A) + (A\cdot \nabla)B + (B\cdot \nabla) A$$

So,
$$\nabla(-p_1 \cdot E_2) = \nabla[p_1 \cdot (\nabla V)]$$
$$=\nabla\left[p_1 \cdot \nabla \left[K_e \frac{p_2 \cdot R_2}{R_2^2}\right]\right]= K_e \nabla\left[p_1 \cdot \nabla \left[p_2 \cdot \frac{R_2}{R_2^2}\right]\right]$$

There are some ambiguities now in your original question which makes it harder to proceed further. Is $\hat{r}$ the same as $\hat{R}_2 ?$ Is one of these dipoles fixed to the origin, and the other is allowed to move around, and the moving around of this dipole is what determines the arguments of $U$?

Comment: Sorry for the delay on getting back to you, but that was exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Use $\nabla\left[\frac{{\vec p}\cdot{\vec r}}{r^3}\right]$=$\frac{\nabla({\vec p}\cdot{\vec r})}{r^3}$+$({\vec p}\cdot{\vec r})\nabla\left(\frac{1}{r^3}\right)$. $\nabla({\vec p}\cdot {\vec r})={\vec p}$ since $\nabla\times{\vec r}=0.$